# Eclipse Plugin: IMarker is not working for AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
.
.
.
.
IEditorPart editorPart = page.getActiveEditor();
IEditorInput input = (editorPart==null)?null:editorPart.getEditorInput();
IFile file=((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();
.
.
IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
```

Now, marker works fine if it is java file, but it does not work for the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not familiar with the editor but it may just be that the Android manifest XML editor does not show markers. Does your marker show in the `Problems` view?

Comment: Yes, the marker show in the Problems view.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has two different notions for displaying error feedback: markers and annotations. By default, error markers display in the problems view, but not in the editors; annotations are used to display stuff inside editors (e.g. errors, bookmarked locations, etc.).

A few years ago I have written this blog post about how to create automatic presentation for your markers. I guess, this is what you will need: http://cubussapiens.hu/2010/11/markers-and-annotations-in-eclipse-for-error-feedback/

Comment: Many editors use classes based on `MarkerAnnotation` to include the markers in the editor annotation model.

Comment: Zoltán Ujhelyi and greg-449, thanks for your replies. I think what I did is working fine. The same code displays different marker signs (which got me confused) in xml and java files. In java files. it is showing "blue-i" marker sign, while in the xml file, it is showing "inverted-i inside a triangle" marker sign.